# Why does Scala's toSeq convert an immutable Set to a mutable ArrayBuffer?

Tags: scala, set, sequence, immutability, scala-collections

If I call `toSeq` on an immutable `Set` collection I get an `ArrayBuffer`.

```
scala> Set(1,2,3).toSeq // returns Seq[Int] = ArrayBuffer(1, 2, 3)
```

This surprises me. Given Scala's emphasis on using immutable data structures, I expect to get back an immutable sequence like a `Vector` or `List` instead of a mutable `ArrayBuffer`. The returned ordering of the set elements should of course be undefined, but there doesn't seem to be any semantic reason why that ordering should also be mutable.

In general, I expect Scala operations to always produce immutable results unless I explicitly request a mutable one. This has been my assumption all along, but it is an incorrect one here, and I actually just spent an hour debugging a problem where the unexpected presence of an `ArrayBuffer` led to a runtime error in a `match` statement. My fix was to change `Set(...).toSeq` to `Set(...).toList`, but this feels like a hack because there's nothing about my application that requires a list in particular at that point.

Is having `Set(...).toSeq` return a mutable object a flaw in Scala's implementation, or is there a principle I am misunderstanding here?

This is Scala 2.9.2.

Comment: Fixed in 2.10-RC2: `scala> Seq(1,2,3).toSeq` -> `res0: Seq[Int] = List(1, 2, 3)`

Comment: @senia, did you mean `Set(1,2,3).toSeq` instead of `Seq(1,2,3).toSeq`?

Comment: Please vote for change: [SI-6570](https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-6570)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[Here](http://grokbase.com/t/gg/scala-internals/12apbqpqbc/seq-aliasing-scala-collection-seq-considered-dangerous) is the recent thread on whether Seq should mean immutable.Seq.

Roland Kuhn:

> collection.Seq not having mutators is not at all a valid defense!

The example of mutable varargs is rather sneaky.

Recently,

```
scala> Set(1,2,3)
res0: scala.collection.immutable.Set[Int] = Set(1, 2, 3)

scala> res0.toSeq
res1: Seq[Int] = ArrayBuffer(1, 2, 3)

scala> res0.to[collection.immutable.Seq]
res2: scala.collection.immutable.Seq[Int] = Vector(1, 2, 3)
```

Comment: It looks like the current answer is "it's controversial", and the linked thread gives a good discussion why. Check out the links in the comments on the original question as well, because from them it seems that the anti-mutabilists are getting their way.

Answer (score 11):

I agree it's a little strange, but I do not believe it is a flaw. First, consider this: the compile-time type of `Set.toSeq` is

```
() => Seq[Int]
```

not

```
() => ArrayBuffer[Int]
```

`ArrayBuffer` just happens to be the run-time type of the returned object (probably because `Set.toSeq` adds to an `ArrayBuffer` and then just returns that without converting).

So, even though `toSeq` is giving you back a mutable object, you can't actually mutate it (without casting, or pattern matching to `ArrayBuffer` -- so the real "strange" part is that Scala lets you pattern match on arbitrary classes). (You have to trust that `Set` doesn't hold on to the object and mutate it, but I think that's a fair assumption to make).

Another way to look at it is, a mutable type is just strictly more specific than an immutable type. Or, another way of saying this is, every mutable object can also be treated as an immutable object: an immutable object has a getter, and a mutable object has a getter *and* a setter -- but it still has a getter.

Of course, this can be abused:

```
val x = new Seq[Int] {
    var n: Int = 0
    def apply(k: Int) = k
    def iterator = {
        n += 1
        (0 to n).iterator
    }
    def length = n
}

x foreach println _
0
1

x foreach println _
0
1
2
```

but, well, so can a lot of things.